# GRPC compression in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, grpc

I'm implementing GRPC on iOS. 
Recently the our server has adopted GZIP compression on all messages. 
How do set the same compression on GRPC clients in Objective C / Swift?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Ross!

The ObjC client accepts server responses compressed with GZip or Deflate, and decompresses them under the hood before passing them up to the application. It doesn't yet compress requests, though. Supporting compression in responses was higher priority, as responses tend to be much much bigger than requests.

The C gRPC library underneath the ObjC one does compress requests on demand, so it's possible to add the feature to the library if one feels adventurous :)

Comment: Thanks for elucidating.